# Differential Drive ROS Plugin stops responding after reset_simulation or reset_world

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a basic differential drive robot that uses the differential drive ros plugin that stops responding after I call `reset_simulation` or `reset_world`.  I'm using ROS Hydro and Gazebo 1.9.  For context, I am trying to collect data on several sets of trajectories (100's of trajectories total), which is why I would like to be able to reset the simulator and drive the next trajectory automatically.

As far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with any code I have written.  When I start up Gazebo and the model loads in an empty world, the model will respond to commands sent on `/cmd_vel`, even using rostopic pub, so I know it's not any problem with code I have written.  After using `rosservice call /gazebo/reset_simulation` or `reset_world`, the position of the model is reset correctly and the simulation continues to run, but commands sent to `/cmd_vel` are ignored.

One hint that might be helpful, is that if I call `reset_simulation`, the `/odom` topic is no longer published to either, but if I call `reset_world`, the `/odom` topic continues to be published (and it indicates a tiny amount of movement in the model).

I'm not sure if this is a bug, or some sort of problem with the way I am specifying my model (it's a pretty simple model, so that seems unlikely), but I have replicated it on two different computers.

Has anyone else run into this issue? If so, how did you resolve it? If it is in fact a bug, where should I submit the bug report?

Thanks in advance for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5194/differential-drive-ros-plugin-stops-responding-after-reset_simulation-or-reset_world/) by [MattDerry](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/603/mattderry/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I just also came across this issue (mildly annoying, but not critical to me). Seems like an issue with the diffdrive plugin. The correct place to file a ticket would be https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 473 on 2014-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2014-02-18**:
You might be right.  I've submitted a ticket: https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/169